# Calculate table() for all variables from a dataset in R

Tags: r, for-loop, summary

I want **R** to calculate tables for all variables in the dataset one after another. I've tried

```
for (variable in names(train)){
  print(paste("The table of", variable, "is: "))
  print(table(variable))
}
```

but it does not give tables as usual when using `table(variable)`. I am 100% sure this is super easy but I just cannot find the way to do it since I am still a beginner. The same goes for `summary()`.

Comment: `table` needs to know the data that `variable` belongs to. Try `table(train[,variable])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the *apply functions. Here is an example:

```
lapply(ChickWeight, table)
```

Same for `summary`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you like the answer, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). -Best, fzk